# SEM model in Lavaan - information matrix could not be inverted

Tags: r, regression, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my model?

R is saying that it may not be identified!

This is what im running:

```
modelo <-'
AcquiringKnowledge =~ A2 + A3 + A4 + A6
FanIdentification =~ F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 + F6 + F7 
UncertaintyOfOutcome =~ U2 + U5 + U6 + U7
Spectatorship =~ AcquiringKnowledge + FanIdentification + UncertaintyOfOutcome

Spectatorship ~ AcquiringKnowledge + FanIdentification + UncertaintyOfOutcome
'
fit <- sem(modelo, data=V1)
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE)
```

It should look like the image, but not with those numbers. I'm having trouble running the regression.[image]

Comment: Programming questions are mostly reserved for stackoverflow. I'd suggest you try over there instead.

Comment: Why the two identical lines? `Spectatorship ~ AcquiringKnowledge + FanIdentification + UncertaintyOfOutcome` Model identification issues generally arise from misspecification of the relationship between indicators and latent variables.